# scrollToRowAtIndexPath scrolls to the second last row instead of the last row

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller, scrollto, viewdidload

I have a messagesTableView which is shown in a ViewController in a NavigationController.

In viewDidLoad:

```
[self.messagesTableView reloadData];
NSInteger t;
if ((t = [self.messagesTableView numberOfRowsInSection:0]) > 0) {
    NSLog(@"ViewDidLoad: number of rows:%d Messages Count:%d", t, [messages count]);
    NSIndexPath* ip = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow: (t-1) inSection:0];
    [self.messagesTableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:ip atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone animated:NO];
}
```

[image: As you can see, the last row is partially shown]

and in viewDidAppear:

```
[self.messagesTableView reloadData];

NSInteger t;
if ((t = [self.messagesTableView numberOfRowsInSection:0]) > 0) {
    NSLog(@"ViewDidAppear: number of rows:%d Messages Count:%d", t, [messages count]);
    NSIndexPath* ip = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow: (t - 1) inSection:0];
    [self.messagesTableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:ip atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:NO];
}
```

[image: The last is shown completely]

The scrollToRowAtIndexPath in viewDidLoad scrolls to second last row instead of the last row whereas the same function in viewDidAppear scrolls to the last row.. The only problem is that it takes a while for the viewDidAppear function to be called..

but why does it behave differently in viewDidLoad and viewDidAppear (the NSLog is printing the same values for both)?

Comment: Can you post the screen shot of those two results?

Answer (score 1):

viewDidAppear is called after ther slide-in animation is complete. You might want to try to set the table view position in viewWillAppear instead, so that the tableview shows at the correct position immediately when it becomes visible.

I think that viewDidLoad gets called after loadView, but before layoutSubviews of the table view. The tableview is added with coordinates not considering the navigation bar at this stage. Then when the viewController is pushed there is another setFrame called by the navigationController to fit the tableView controller's view into it's area. This moves the table view down by approx 44 points, causing the bottom cell to disappear.

All this resizing is over in viewWillAppear, so that's the best place to do that.

Comment: that makes sense.. but the result is the same even if I keep it in viewWillAppear.

Comment: What is the result that you getting?

Comment: I think you are right about the tableview not being resized before viewdidappear.. so if the last row's height is more, then it shown partially. which means that the tableview is actually scrolling to the last row but the tableview has occupied more height that it is supposed to. but I am getting the same result in viewWillAppear too

Comment: where are you creating the UITableView? Is it the main view of the view controller you are pushing? If not, does it have the flexible height autoresizing mask on? It needs that or else the height will be too large.

Comment: It has the flexible height autoresizing mask.. thats why it is being resized to the right height after in viewdidappear
the tableview is a subview of the viewController.. I have posted screenshots in my question.. please take a look

Comment: Try moving the reloadData to willAppear. That's all I can help you without actually personally de debug your code.

Answer (score 0):

Just place your `scrollToBottom` code:

```
[self.messagesTableView reloadData];
NSInteger t;
if ((t = [self.messagesTableView numberOfRowsInSection:0]) > 0) {
    NSLog(@"ViewDidLoad: number of rows:%d Messages Count:%d", t, [messages count]);
    NSIndexPath* ip = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow: (t-1) inSection:0];
    [self.messagesTableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:ip atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone animated:NO];
}
```

into **`-(void)viewWillLayoutSubviews`** method;

And note that make sure `animated:NO`;